# Groovy map internal representation

Tags: groovy

I understand that groovy uses `java.util.ArrayList` to represent objects created using array literals like so: `arr = []`. I wanted to understand what underlying object groovy uses to create a map created like so: `my_map = [:]`. I wrote this code below:

```
 7 array = []
  8 array[1] = 'a'
  9 array[2] = 'b'
 10 println array.class.name
 11 println array
 12 
 13 my_map = [:]
 14 my_map['OK'] = 200
 15 println my_map.class
 16 println my_map
```

The output produced by code above is:

```
java.util.ArrayList
[null, a, b]
null
[OK:200]
```

Notice the `.class` attribute is missing on `my_map`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Groovy uses [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) for map literals BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_map` is a Map.  In groovy `map.key` is a convenience to get the value associated with the key from the map.

The issue here is that it's looking for a key named `class`, and there isn't one.

To get the class of a Map, you need to explicitly ask for it with `my_map.getClass()`